# Prism DelegateCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Добрый день, возникла внезапная проблема, может кто сталкивался.

Создал отдельную сборку для большого проекта под wpf, там используется prism 4,
пишу обычную ViewModel, с точки зрения статического анализатора - всё в полном порядке, при компиляции сборки ошибка компиляции `csc.exe`, без всяких дополнительных данных.

При удалении `DelegateCommand` - сборка начинает компилироваться, при использовании `NotificationObject` и `ICommand` - тоже всё хорошо, но как только объявляю `DelegateCommand` - ошибка компиляции. Может нужно какую-то сборку ещё дополнительно подтягивать? 
О которой не знает ни анализатор студии, ни решарпер?

Comment: А _какая_ ошибка компиляции?

Comment: И каким именно образом вы удаляете `DelegateCommand`? Вы имеете в виду `Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.DelegateCommand`, правильно?

Comment: `DelegateCommand` из `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands`, прямо в исходнике закоментил, юзинг оставил.

ошибка "csc.exe", всё, никаких подробностей по ней нет, даже кода ошибки

Comment: Ну сделайте полный rebuild. А зачем понадобилось модифицировать майкрософтовские исходники? Откуда вам пришла в голову идея, что нужно закомментировать `DelegateCommand`?

Comment: Почему модифицировать исходники ms?

Это моя вью моделька, в ней нет ничего особенного, стал убирать всё специфичное для wpf, чтоб скомпилилось, путём исключения - локализовал проблему.

Солюшен полностью чистил, билдил, не помогло.

Comment: А почему ваша команда находится в неймспейсе `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands`?

Comment: Как это нет кода ошибки? А можно лог компиляции?

Comment: Это вроде как [стандарт](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands(v=pandp.50).aspx)?

Comment: Проблема решена, недоставало PresentationCore. Спасибо

Comment: Напишите тогда ответ что ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было подключить reference `PresentationCore`